# Div displaying weird in IE - there's a surprise

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

```css
body {
    background: #9cdcf9 url(/images/left_cloud.png) bottom left no-repeat;
    font-family:\"Trebuchet MS\";
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
}
#cloud-container {
    width: 100%;
    background: url(/images/right_cloud.png) bottom right no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
}
#plane-container {
    width: 100%;
    background: url(/images/plane.png) top right no-repeat;
    height: 20%;
}
#footer1 {
     width:100%;
     height: 180px;
     background: url(/images/footer.png) bottom center repeat-x;
     vertical-align: bottom;
     text-align: center;
     color: #fff;
     text-shadow: #555 1px 1px 1px;
     font-size: 11px;
}
```

Works perfect in FF but makes the page fall to the left and divs overlap - does anyone know what it is in the css that IE is not liking? -  bit of a long shot, but hey....

Comment: Can you post the HTML your applying the styles to or it's too hard to guess what might be happening.

Comment: Screenshot of the problems would be nice too!

Comment: Well if those backslashes in `font-family` exist in the original CSS you might want to start there. It's messing up the syntax highlighting here, as well as screwing with the code highlighting in my Textmate.  I also vaguely remember IE doing something with backslashes… It was a CSS hack.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is difficult to tell from your question without the html or image, I think the answer to your problem could be to float your divs.

```
#cloud-container, #plane-container, #footer1{
    float:left;
}
```

You might also want to check out this page for [common IE CSS issues](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/internet-explorer.shtml)